# Set up on Mac OS X - play framework2

Tags: macos, playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm tried to set up playframe work on OSX and bumped into some troubles.

1. Download Typesafe Activator and set up as this procedure. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/
2. "activator new test" -> "cd test" -> "activator run"
3. Access localhost:9000 with Safari to get a message Failed to open page
4. Some error messages are there as below.

Is there any idea to solve the problem?

```
    % activator run                                                                                                                                          +[master]
    [info] Loading project definition from /Users/w256/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/000.now/vo/scala-getting-started/project
    [info] Updating {file:/Users/w256/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/000.now/vo/scala-getting-started/project/}scala-getting-started-build...
    [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
    [info] Done updating.
    [info] Set current project to play-getting-started (in build file:/Users/w256/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/000.now/vo/scala-getting-started/)
    [info] Updating {file:/Users/w256/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/000.now/vo/scala-getting-started/}root...
    [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
    [info] Done updating.
    [warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
    [warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
    [warn]  * io.netty:netty:3.10.1.Final -> 3.10.4.Final
    [warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

    --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

    [info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

    (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)



    [error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:90) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
    [error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:90) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
    [error] p.c.s.n.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:90) ~[play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
```

"activator ui" makes similar errors as below.

```
    % activator ui                                                                                                                                           +[master]
    Found previous process id: 9525
    Local repository: activator-launcher-local @ file:/usr/local/Cellar/typesafe-activator/1.3.6/libexec/repository
    Local repository: activator-local @ file:/Users/w256/Downloads/activator-dist-1.3.7/repository
    Play server process ID is 12608
    [info] play - Application started (Prod)
    [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
    [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:366) ~[play_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.5.7.Final.jar:na]
```

build.sbt is here.

```
name := """play-getting-started"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "org.jscience" % "jscience" % "4.3.1",
  ws,
  "com.typesafe.play" % "play-netty-server_2.11" % "2.4.3" force(),
  "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.10.4.Final" force(),
  "com.typesafe.netty" % "netty-http-pipelining" % "1.1.4" force()
)

libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _ )
```

Comment: Why are you forcing different Netty versions? This is the most likely cause, the error specifies a missing method coming from the Netty internals.

Comment: Which seed/template did you use for new app?

Comment: What @gpgekko meant is: remove that:   "com.typesafe.netty" % "netty-http-pipelining" % "1.1.4" force()" and also remove this:   "com.typesafe.play" % "play-netty-server_2.11" % "2.4.3" force()  and this:   "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.10.4.Final" force()